# Colors in design manual, doesn't fits to real color displayed on monitor

Tags: color, mac

I have an interesting problem. I opened design manual for one logo in Preview in mac. There was showed the colour of a logo with the numeric representation of that colour.

But when I picked the colour with Color picker, I have got a different colour number. See picture. Am I missing something or it is normal?

Thanks for a help.

[image: different between real color and written color number]

Comment: You should find that you have a different colour profile for different aspects of your kit.  There'll be one for your monitor, one for your scanner, one for your printer, and even separae ones for particular pieces of software.  They're all slightly different but attempt to match what you see on the device as closely as possible to a set standard.  Visually, this can be affected by other things, such as changing the brightness and contrast on the device itself, but these changes should not affect the colour's RGB (etc) colour.

Comment: It is possible with certain software to turn colour matching off if it's not necessary.

Comment: Ok, do you know, what steps I have to do on mac, to have a same color what I see, and what is written?

Comment: No - there really should be no hard colour codes there, as they will relate to the profile of the user using them at the time. Perhaps [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19045?locale=en_US) may be your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal and it should not be... but it is.

Every Corporate Image Manual should include what color profiles are being used.

In RGB mode probably you should stay witn adobe 1998, but try to experiment on the CMYK value depending on where you live, Europe or US.

One problem is that in US there are more profiles to choose from. In my opinion the basic one (and I do not mean limited, but as fundamental) is Swop V2. But they probably used some version of Gracol or some version of Fogra.

The problem is that yes, there is much discrepancy.

For now try to stick with the manual.

Comment: ok, Thanks for an answer. So I have to use Color sync utility in mac to change color profile?